# c# console app to send email automatically

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I would like to send an automated email message using c# and outlook. I am confused how to actually send the email, i thought the .Send() method would execute this but nothing happens when i run this and i do not get any compilation errors.

Does anyone know how to activate/execute this code or know somewhere I am messing up. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace email
{
    class Program
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            SendEmailtoContacts();
        }

        private void SendEmailtoContacts()
        {
            string subjectEmail = "test results ";
            string bodyEmail = "test results";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application appp = new  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder sentContacts = 
            appp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.O    lDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

            foreach (Outlook.ContactItem contact in sentContacts.Items)
            {
                if (contact.Email1Address.Contains("gmail.com"))
                {
                    this.CreateEmailItem(subjectEmail, contact.Email1Address, bodyEmail);
                }
            }
        }

        private void CreateEmailItem(string subjectEmail,string toEmail, string bodyEmail)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem eMail = 
            app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            eMail.Subject = subjectEmail;
            eMail.To = toEmail;
            eMail.Body = bodyEmail;
            eMail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

        }
    } 
}
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CORRECT CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;


namespace email
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        SendEmailtoContacts();
        CreateEmailItem("yo", "EMAIL@WHATEVER.COM", "yoyoyoyoyo");
    }

    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        SendEmailtoContacts();
    }

    private static void SendEmailtoContacts()
    {
        string subjectEmail = "test results ";
        string bodyEmail = "test results";
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application appp = new  
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder sentContacts =
```

appp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.O
     lDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

```
        foreach (Outlook.ContactItem contact in sentContacts.Items)
        {
            if (contact.Email1Address.Contains("gmail.com"))
            {
                CreateEmailItem(subjectEmail, contact.Email1Address,
bodyEmail);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void CreateEmailItem(string subjectEmail, string    
 toEmail,     string bodyEmail)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem eMail =

 app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        eMail.Subject = subjectEmail;
        eMail.To = toEmail;
        eMail.Body = bodyEmail;
        eMail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
        ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();
    }



} 
}
```

Comment: why are you using Interop you can do this much easier using `SMTP` if you would like a working method I can post one for you with much less code that works I notice also that you have a Main entry point.. but you are not executing any code.. so how do you expect to actually launch any code.. ?

Comment: Need some more details--Can you debug the addin? Is your SendEmailtoContacts() function ever getting called on ThisAddIn_Startup? If you comment out the .Send() line then the Outlook window should actually remain open on your desktop and you should be able see the email waiting to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

Your question title says "c# **console app** to send email automatically" but you appear to be using code that was meant for an Outlook **AddIn**. The addin is meant to call the SendEmail function upon startup of the addin which would execute `ThisAddIn_Startup`:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // this is never executed because it isn't an outlook addin
        SendEmailtoContacts();
    }

    private void SendEmailtoContacts()
    {
       // sends your email... if it actually gets called
    }
```

Instead try calling that `SendEmailtoContacts()` function from your `Main()` because it is a console app and `Main()` is what is actually executed when you run it:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SendEmailtoContacts();
        }
```

For further debugging, as I noted in a comment, because this is outlook interop you should be able to see these operations taking place in an outlook window as they are executed on your local desktop. For example, if you comment out the final `((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();` line and run the program you should be left with an email waiting for you to click the send button after your program terminates.

---

It looks like you'll also have to modify the method signatures of the other functions to static methods and get rid of the *this* reference in this.CreateEmailItem?

```
        public static void SendEmailtoContacts()
        {
            string subjectEmail = "test results ";
            string bodyEmail = "test results";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application appp = new  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder sentContacts = 
            appp.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.O    lDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

            foreach (Outlook.ContactItem contact in sentContacts.Items)
            {
                if (contact.Email1Address.Contains("gmail.com"))
                {
                    CreateEmailItem(subjectEmail, contact.Email1Address, bodyEmail);
                }
            }
        }

        public static void CreateEmailItem(string subjectEmail,string toEmail, string bodyEmail)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new  
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem eMail = 
            app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            eMail.Subject = subjectEmail;
            eMail.To = toEmail;
            eMail.Body = bodyEmail;
            eMail.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceLow;
            ((Outlook._MailItem)eMail).Send();
        }
```

Comment: i cannot call SendEmailtoContacts() in main. Visual Studio wont recognize it as a method so i tried making it public static and now there is an error under the foreach where it says this.CreateEmailItem. and outlook doesnt come up at all when i run this. The reason i want to use outlook is that this is for my job and there are security blocks everywhere, i was told to use outlook because it would use my current credential to log in and send

Comment: You're on the right track recgnizing that it wasn't a static method so SendEmailtoContacts couldn't be called. The other issue is that because this was an addon *this* must have referred to some other function that creates an email

Comment: yeah, i mean im optimizing someone elses code so it might be best to speak with them because i might be missing something. ill play around with the smtp way. Im not gunna lie its kind of bothering me how i cant get this to work, has anyone had success in using the outlook add in an automated way, ive done it with windows forms apps but i just want to run an exe that will send the email. jw thanks all for help

Comment: Oh, the problem was just that the CreateEmailItem function wasn't a static method and you were trying to access it with *this*

Answer (score 0):

you could use SMTP to do this

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Configuration;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   SendEmail("Lukeriggz@gmail.com", "This is a Test email", "This is where the Body of the Email goes");
}

public static void SendEmail(string sTo, string subject, string body)
{
    var Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]);
    using (var client = new SmtpClient(Your EmailHost, Port))
    using (var message = new MailMessage()
    {
        From = new MailAddress(FromEmail),
        Subject = subject,
        Body = body
    })
    {
        message.To.Add(sTo);
        client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailCredential"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"]);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(message);
    };
}
```

if you want a list of contacts to send the same email then create a `List<string>` and using a foreach loop add them to the `message.To.Add(sTo)` portion of the code.. pretty straight forward..

if you insist on using Outlook to send emails then looks at this MSDN link

[Programmatically Send E-Mail Programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268749.aspx)

Comment: im getting red squigglies everywhere on that smtp snippet, what namespace are u using? just Symstem.net....after i type int.PArse there is no option for Configuration manager, im trying to figure out if im moissing a reference , thanks

Comment: I will update.. keep in mind I am not using Interop so these will not be needed in my working example 
`using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;`

Comment: yeah i got interop to work now i am trying to use smtp, im trying to write code that utilizes smtp also

Comment: smtp is simpler then Interop not sure why you're having such issues ..perhaps if you update your question and post code that pertains to what I have shown you.. I have tested this in a Console app just now.. and It works like a charm.

Comment: can u explain this line [ var Port int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]);

Comment: it says configurationManager name does not exist in this context, is this pseudocode or should i be able to type this in directly

Comment: @Lukeriggz do you know how to read values from `App.Config`or `Web.Config` ? I will post that as well you will need to add the assembly to the References as well also the code is pretty straight forward so you can replace the variables with hardcoded values to test with..but I would not keep hard coded username / passwords inside code

Comment: well `I don't know is not a valid excuse` anyway if you are not sure on something then just use google for example you could have put `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings` in a google search and it would have yielded plenty of examples on what it is and how to use it.. show more effort on your part next time .. in all due respect.. Cheers ! it's the weekend..

Comment: i only said that cus u said u were gunna post that code, "do you know how to read values from App.Configor Web.Config ? I will post that as well " i am googling it on my part, dont offer things then change ur mind.... cheers

Comment: I put the using that's what you need you are confusing the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100812/discussion-between-lukeriggz-and-methodman).